# Erro Hospedagem - Zend Framework 2

Tags: framework, zend

Estou hospedando um sistema criado em Zend 2 em um servidor dedicado com Windows Server 2008, Apache 2.4, PHP 7.1.5.

O usuário que está rodando o apache já está com permissão total nos arquivos, mas estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/DoctrineAnnotations.php'
>   (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\urldosite.com.br\vendor\doctrine\annotations\lib\Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry.php
>   on line 64

Alguém sabe como posso resolver?

Answer (score 0):

use `__DIR__` para pegar o caminho correto, se estiver usando autoloader revise o mesmo esta carregando o que você precisa.

`require_once(__DIR__."path/arquivo.php")`